# How to refer to current dom element in array for changing activity via the listener

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

Currently, I'm looping through all my images and making their onmouseover/onmouseout events change their image with a for-loop.

```
 var arrows = document.getElementsByClassName('arrow');

 for (var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++) {
     arrows[i].onmouseover = arrows[i] + ".src = 'images/downarrow_hover.gif';";
     arrows[i].onmouseout = arrows[i] + ".src = 'images/downarrow.gif';";
 }
```

It's not working, am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign functions to `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

```
var arrows = document.getElementsByClassName('arrow');

for (var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++) {
    arrows[i].onmouseover = function () {
        this.src = 'images/downarrow_hover.gif';
    };

    arrows[i].onmouseover = function () {
        this.src = 'images/downarrow.gif';
    };
```

For what it's worth and if you can afford to, you should look into [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) which makes it a breeze to do [a such thing](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('.arrow').hover(
    function () { $(this).attr('src', 'images/downarrow_hover.gif'); },
    function () { $(this).attr('src', 'images/downarrow.gif'); });
```

Comment: thank you, apparently i had forgotten the very intuitive concept that events execute functions. as for the jquery, I now realize it's better to just simply use css background-image positioning on a css sprite for this type of thing.